# Path tracer fireflies

Tags: glsl, raytracing, pbr

I'm trying to make a path tracer but I have no idea how do I solve fireflies problem when sampling from env map. Env maps usually contain really bright and small areas and when some ray hits that really bright region we go a firefly. My image looks this:
[render with fireflies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBQqd.jpg)

I tried removing them by clamping max luminance of the pixel in the shader like following:

```
const float maxLuminance = 10.0f;
float lum = dot(hitValue, vec3(0.212671f, 0.715160f, 0.072169f));
if(lum > maxLuminance)
{
    hitValue *= maxLuminance / lum;
}
```

But this results in very bland and dark image:
[render without fireflies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1uB0.jpg)

So my question is: How do I keep those sun shadows from Env map like on the first image (best visible on the green wall) but eliminate all the noise?